# overwrite $location pushState history AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I am a returning user to a "*results page*" I want to see the last filters I used. So I am using `ngCookies` to update the last used search parameters on a page.

```
controller('Results', ['$location','$cookies',function($location,$cookies){
    $location.search(angular.fromJson($cookies.search));
}]);

//will yield: /results?param1=dude&param2=bro
```

However, if I click "*back*" I will not be brought to the last page I would expect.

**That's because another state was pushed onto the history but was unperceived by the user.**

The user landed on `/results` but the controller immediately pushed `/results?param1=dude&param2=bro` onto the state history.

How do I overwrite or delete the state `/results` so that "*back*" would return me to what a user would expect the last page they came from to be?

Comment: Can you use $location.replace(); ? I'm looking at http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chain `replace()` onto the end of your $location.search call:

```
controller('Results', ['$location','$cookies',function($location,$cookies){
    $location.search(angular.fromJson($cookies.search)).replace();
}]);
```

This causes the last history entry to be replaced, rather than a new one added.

There is also the [reloadOnSearch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeProvider) option which you can set to `false` to prevent reloading a route when the search params change (if you want the back button to go to `/results`).